# Web app polling status too chatty

Tags: angularjs, status, polling

Have an Angular web app that track status of many objects.  Now, I have a directive for each object to poll a nodejs server for status.  This works but it is quite chatty and I am a bit worried about scalability.  However, the backend does not support subscription so it could not use a pusher.  One option is to let the nodejs server do the polling and push status back.  Then nodejs need to keep a list of objects to poll and client probably need to check the message to determine whether a status needs update.  Really appreciate your suggestion for a better strategy.

Answer (score 0):

You can use firebase and load the data from a third party source into the firebase database then use angular-fire to get that data into the app... alternatively you could use a socket connection to DIY.  In either scenario, I assume like you said the NodeJS portion on the server will need to handle polling the third party system for data and populating the firebase instance which would be a read-only layer as far as the system is concerned... changes would be sent directly to the third party and NodeJS would just be responsible for updating the firebase DB.